# How does `cat`'s I/O model differ from that of other utilities?

Tags: text-processing, cat, io, stdout, stdin

From the output of `stdbuf --help` (GNU):

```
Usage: stdbuf OPTION... COMMAND
Run COMMAND, with modified buffering operations for its standard streams.
...

NOTE: If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams ('tee' does
for example) then that will override corresponding changes by 'stdbuf'.
Also some filters (like 'dd' and 'cat' etc.) don't use streams for I/O,
and are thus unaffected by 'stdbuf' settings.
```

I am confused as to what the precise definition of "streams for I/O" in this context is and how this applies to `cat` in specific. If it doesn't use the standard I/O streams, then what does it use? Pertinent man pages and web search failed to provide further insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `stdbuf` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html#stdbuf-invocation) is slightly more explicit:

> *command* must start with the name of a program that
>
> 1. uses the ISO C `FILE` streams for input/output (note the programs `dd` and `cat` don’t do that),
> 2. does not adjust the buffering of its standard streams (note the program `tee` is not in this category).

The ISO C `FILE` streams are streams such as those returned by [`fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), as opposed to [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). `stdbuf` works by preloading a `libstdbuf` library which tweaks the `FILE` streams which the C library wraps around the standard input, output and/or error; programs which don’t use those streams aren’t affected. GNU `cat` for example uses [either its standard input file descriptor, or a file descriptor returned by `open`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c?id=ece7157933fea925da10b5c3e7ace1f0fb2d9f50#n663).

Answer (score 5):

`dd` and `cat` use the `read(2)` and `write(2)` system calls directly, not the buffered C stdio functions (`fread(3)`, `fwrite(3)`, `printf(3)`), so any change to stdio doesn't affect them.

`stdbuf(1)` works by preloading a small dynamic library (with `LD_PRELOAD`, or `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` on Mac) that overrides some functions from stdio in order to use the buffering strategy desired by the user, not the one used by default by the program.